# casperjs scroll popup layer

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

i have that "popup container" and have to scroll it to the bottom before i can click a link.

```
<div id="tos-popup-container" class="tos-popup-container">
<div id="tos-scroll" class="tos-scroll-area" tabindex="0">
<div id="tos-header" class="tos-header">
<div id="header-text-div">Privacy and Terms</div>
</div>
<div id="tos-text" class="tos-text-div">
</div>
<div id="tos-button-div" class="tos-button-div">
</div>
```

i've tried it allready with:

```
this.evaluate(function() {   return window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight; });
```

and

```
casper.scrollToBottom();
casper.wait(1000, function () {
    casper.capture("scroll.png");
});
```

but both doesnt work. i think, first i have to select the element #tos-popup-container or #tos-scroll and then "scroll down".

Comment: hey @swapfile, if u dont mind share with me a little bit of explanation.
What do u mean by select the element? Is that means your simulating:
A) pressing tab until it highlight into that element or 
B) click directly to that element?

I wonder.... why the scroll is "a must"? Wouldn't enough for a direct to simulate the A or B Actions i mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 3):

i have solved it with

```
this.sendKeys('#tos-text', casper.page.event.key.PageDown , {keepFocus: true});
```

but there's maybe a better way!

Comment: You are trying to scroll the google TOS right? ahah your article was useful to me thanks!